# Are there any web-based, standalone (no-install), or no-admin installer compilers for C#

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I'm looking to spend a bit of my lunch break each day teaching myself some C#. I have access to some books on the subject via my employer-paid Books24x7 subscription, but I have no way of running code while I'm at work.

My work PC is rather locked down (no admin privileges, read-only "Program Files" - though install to a desktop-based folder is possible, and USB thumbdrives are forbidden..), so I'm looking for another way to compile some code.

Can anyone point to:
* A web-based compiler (binary download from a known-good site, or possibly a web-based CLI to interact with non-GUI apps)
* A standalone compiler requiring no-install
* A compiler which does not require admin right to install.

Thanks!

---

**[Edit 1]**
I suppose another reason why I mentioned the web-based compiler first was that I'm not sure which version(s) of the .Net framework might be installed on my work machine. We do absolutely no .Net work on my project so there's no reason to believe there's anything more than what came with XP. If there's a way to install the latest version without admin privileges, I'd love to hear it!

Comment: Maybe getting a laptop and taking that to work my be a better option , just so you can install what even you like on it then. ;)

Comment: I've considered that, and have done it before actually, but I'm not sure how well it would go over these days since my employer has been a little more worker-hostile than they used to be (and they've always been bad). I suppose I'd likely be OK since I wouldn't be hooked into the LAN.

Comment: Yeah but I mean if it's at lunch and not connected to LAN then I really don't see how they could stop you.  Personally for you I think it would be that best, It will let you experiment a bit more with out restrictions.

Comment: Do you work at the CIA or the NSA? Your employer seems rather draconian. I hope you are not already a programmer. I would hate to work in conditions as you have described.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the .Net Framework installed on your computer, then you should already have a compiler.

It will be in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[VERSION]\`

It's called `csc.exe`.

This should work without any administrator priviledges.

Answer (score 1):

### There's [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/).

It can compile and server-side run several languages that usually require the language to be installed on the client's PC. For me, I can write and run any C# applications without having Visual Studio or the latest .NET Framework installed.